# Keep a bouncing ball centered in stage

Tags: actionscript

I have a ball bouncing on a paddle. I want the "stage" to move vertically in order to always keep the ball centered. Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest a stationary ball and a bouncing paddle.

Comment: Im thinking of doing something similar to Doodle Jump and I dont see how a bouncing paddle would help me. Could you please explain a little closer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the ball centered in stage, why not move the stage so the ball is centered?

Ie, in your rendering method, just add `-bx+sw/2, -by+sh/2` to everything, where `(bx,by)` is your ball position and `(sw,sh)` is your screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not have been more beneficial to place all items in a sprite/movieclip and then the ball on stage, that way instead of moving "the stage" you are actually moving a movieclip that holds everything (except the ball).